# Migrating Asp .net 1.1 app from IIS 6(Windows03) to IIS 7(Windows08)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

We have a Asp.net 1.1 app running on IIS 6(Windows03), after upgrading the windows server to 2008 it stopped responding when I hit the app URL in browser(it just keeps spinning). I've been doing some research on this and almost every article pointing me to http://blogs.iis.net/bills/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008 this one. I did all the steps mentioned in this article but still my application is not running on IIS 7(Windows08). Is there anything else that I can try? can someone please help me this?

Comment: Did you check IIS Logs to find out what's happening?

Comment: I did check the logs, everything looks normal nothing unusual

Comment: Did you check from IIS if the authentication/authorization is showing okay? Did you check from other browser if you see anything different?

Comment: Hard to tell without the actual error. Do u run the app from the 1.1 net pool?

Comment: @Artem, yes I am running the app on 1.1 pool

Comment: @nimesh Yes authentication is okay and other browser Chrome is doing the same thing its just spinning

Comment: Check if this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515251(v=vs.140).aspx) helps.